# WebFluxSecurity does not add Authentication to SecurityContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have this strange issue with Spring Cloud Security with the reactive stack. I setup Spring Cloud Gateway and at the same time, I made it be a RsourceServer so all incoming requests will have JWT granted from Firebase in this case. Here are some snapshots from my configuration.

`application.yml` Set JWK and Issuer, to tell spring security how JWT's should be validated.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
          issuer-uri: https://securetoken.google.com/${project_name}
```

`SecurityConfig`

```
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {

      @Bean
      public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/public").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated().and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
        return http.build();
        // @formatter:on
      }
    }
```

and finally the controller

`TestController` just for test purposes I created Controller to check if security context is set or not.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

  @GetMapping("/public")
  public String getPublic() {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Public API should not have any AuthContext");
    }

    return "All shiny you got your PUBLIC data!";
  }

  @GetMapping("/private")
  public String getPrivate(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
    log.info(jwt.getTokenValue());    //in here jwt present as should be
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Oops.... Private API should have AuthContext");
    }

    return "All shiny you got your PRIVATE data!";
  }

}
```

So I am super frustrated and hope someone can help me out here. according to all Spring Security docs, I dug into it seems to me that I should have my security context saved when JWT is valid.

The main purpose is to be able to use `ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction` Which tries to get Authentication and token out of it and pass it downstream to other services in WebClient.
However, it is NULL.

[Bearer Token Propagation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#bearer-token-propagation) here it is clearly written that SecurityContext should be valid at that point already.

Any suggestions would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Try using the [ReactiveSecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.html)

Comment: Hi, @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, Thanks for your response, actually I tried that in the first place however if you check the ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction implementation you will see that it uses exactly ReactiveSecurityContextHolder. And it is still empty.

Comment: `@AuthenticationPrincipal` uses the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`, and my understanding is that that is working as expected. It may be helpful to take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5207). If you are able to reproduce this behaviour in a minimal sample, then I could help with debugging.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, So now I know the "issue" if I can call it issue, 

I am configuring my Security in above-mentioned way. 
```
.oauth2ResourceServer()
 .jwt(); 
```
So the problem here is that Spring-Security assumes that you are going stateless when you are a ResourceServer and they use UNconfigurable NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository which is just Mono.empty(). What is for me interesting if I can somehow still keep using same setup and get a benefit of `ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder and chain it to the response of your Rest controller.

Your RestController needs to return a Mono or Flux for that as well.

e.g.

```
return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .map { securityContext -> securityContext.authentication }
    .map { authentication -> authentication.principal }
```